# Copy constructor called on *this

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor

I defined a copy constructor for a class `A`. Due to an unfortunate macro expansion, I ended up compiling the following:

```
A a = a;
```

I (eventually) realized this results in a call to `A::A(const A& rhs)` with `this==&rhs`.

1. Why does the compiler allow this? Conceptually I would assume that since `a` is declared in this statement, it wouldn't yet be available for use on the RHS.
2. Should I defensively check `this==&rhs` whenever I define a copy constructor?

I am using gcc version 5.4.0 with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Note clang++ with default options gives the warning "warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]".  Unfortunately, it seems "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic" doesn't have any similar warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In a declaration, the identifier being declared is in scope as soon as it appears.  There are some valid uses of this, e.g. `void *p = &p;`
2. It's normal for the copy-constructor to assume no self-copy, leaving it up to the caller to not make this mistake.  Preferably, follow the rule of zero.

It would be better to not write `A a = a;` in the first place. To avoid this you could get in the habit of using `auto`, e.g.

```
#define F(x) auto a = A(x)

#define G(x) A a = x
```

Now if you write `G(a);` you silently get the bug, but `F(a);` fails to compile.

Comment: This rule is more important in C than modern C++ because of the helpful idiom `Thing* things = malloc(n * sizeof *things);` but carried over to C++ in any case.